# How to access a widget from one screen inside another screen in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

How do I access a widget from screen1 and make changes to it in screen2 and also return screen1 back to it initial state(like I just run the code).
I have commented out some code that is not working.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenManagement, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class Screen2(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen2, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.retry = Button(text='retry', font_size=15, size_hint=(.26, .26),
                            pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .32}, on_press=self.retrying,
                            background_color=(0, 0, 1, 1))
        self.add_widget(self.retry)

    def retrying(self, *args):
        self.manager.current = 'screen1'
        # it should change the text in screen1 to "i am back to screen1, thanks you"
        #self.welc.text=" i am back to screen1, thank you"
        # it should change the button color back to it normal state
        #self.goto.background_color='normal state'


class Screen1(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.welc = Label(text='hi there welcome to my first screen', font_size=15, size_hint=(.26, .26),
                          pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .7})
        self.add_widget(self.welc)

        self.goto = Button(text='next screen', font_size=15, size_hint=(.2, .2),
                       pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .32}, on_press=self.going, background_color=(0, 0, 1, 1))
        self.add_widget(self.goto)

    def going(self, *args):
        self.goto.background_color=(1,0,0,1)
        self.manager.current = 'screen2'

class Application(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManagement(transition=FadeTransition())
        sm.add_widget(Screen1(name='screen1'))
        sm.add_widget(Screen2(name='screen2'))
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application().run()
```

My question is this:

1. how do i change the text in screen1 when the retry button is pressed.
2. How do i return screen1 back to it initial state after the retry button is pressed so that the "next screen" button color changes back to blue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have changed the current screen to `screen1`, then you can access that `Screen` as `self.manager.current_screen`, so your `retrying()` method can be:

```
def retrying(self, *args):
    self.manager.current = 'screen1'
    self.manager.current_screen.welc.text = "i am back to screen1, thanks you"
    self.manager.current_screen.goto.background_color = background_color=(0, 0, 1, 1)
```

To set the `screen1` back to its original state, you could write another method that just sets all the values back to the original value one by one. Or you could recreate `screen1` by doing something like this in a method of your `Application`.:

```
def reset_screen1(self):
    sm = self.root
    scr1 = sm.get_screen('screen1`)
    sm.remove_widget(scr1)
    sm.add_widget(Screen1(name='screen1'))
```

Comment: how do I then reset the screen1 back to it original state, I mean  how do I make screen1 be as if I just run the code

Comment: I have added some additional information to my answer above.

Comment: when I tried to reset screen1 using the code above I got an error 'screen2' object has no attribute 'root'

Comment: Yes, not knowing where you would want such a method, I mentioned that it is written as a method of your `Application` class. If you make it a method of `Screen2`,  then change `sm = self.root` to `sm = self.manager`.

Comment: can you please explain the code for the reset screen.  Cause it only reset  the goto button color and didn't change the text back to it previous text.